# How to convert in Pyspark a column of 10 millions records into columns of 20000 records?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

As you can see in the image, we have a dataframe with one column that contains 10 millions values. Our intention is to reshape this dataframe and get one that divides the 10 million values in columns of 20000 values. Is there any way to perform this action in Pyspark?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvZKf.png

Next, I add an image where you can see what I want to achieve. The image shows an example of input values (point in which we are) and output values (result we want to achieve).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gJHg.png

I have one more doubt, the next step is convert the columns into rows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/udHbk.png

Comment: Can you try to give sample data within the question + some example input and output?

Comment: I have added an image with some example input and output. Many thanks.

Comment: It would be even easier if you didn't provide an image but actually give the values so they can be copy pasted by anyone who wants to give it a try :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible way (I have generated data of the form in the image, the exact sizes can be toggled by adjusting the input parameters for `generate_data`):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

def generate_data(size=10000, colsize=200):
    # generate data with a partition marker every colsize rows
    # to mark where the next column begins
    data = (sc.parallelize(np.random.rand(size).tolist())
            .zipWithIndex()
            .toDF(schema=['value', 'rownum'])
           .withColumn('colnum',(f.col('rownum')/colsize).cast('integer')))

    # generate a row number within column
    win = Window.partitionBy('colnum').orderBy('rownum')
    data = data.withColumn('col_rownum', f.rank().over(win))
    return data

df = generate_data(size=10010)

# now pivot to get columns
pivoted = (df.groupby('col_rownum')
           .pivot('colnum')
           .max('value')
           .orderBy('col_rownum'))

pivoted.select(pivoted.columns[1:])
```

Comment: The code works and we have obtained the desired result. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I have one more doubt, the next step is convert the columns into rows. I have uploaded an image of what we want to achieve.

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance. In terms of the follow-on, just to make sure my understanding is correct, you are looking to transpose the DF, correct?

Comment: OK will try and take a look this afternoon

Comment: Have you find something?